# In Dart, how do I get code completion when using noSuchMethod?

Tags: dart

I'd like to use noSuchMethod to reduce boilerplate when writing a lot of similar methods. But then the API is worse for my library's users because code completion no longer works. I tried this but I get warnings about unimplemented methods:

```dart
class ThingMixin {
  foo();
  bar();
  noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to define the API in a separate class:

```dart
abstract class ThingApi {
  foo();
  bar();
}

class ThingMixin implements ThingApi {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) {
    ...
  }
}
```

(Note that noSuchMethod cannot call super if you want it to work as a mixin.)